# C Output Ambiguity

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

Void swap (char*,char*);

Int main()
{

  Char *pstr[2]={    
    “Hello”
    “good morning”
  }

  Swap (pstr[0],pstr[1]);

  Printf (“%s\n%s”,pstr[0],pstr[1]);

  Return 0;

}

Void swap (char *11,char*12)   
{

  Char *t;

  T=11 ;

  T1=12;

  12=1;

}

Good morning Hello

Addresses of “Hello” and “ Good morning”

Hello Good morning

Gello Hood morning

Answer C
```

why are these two strings not getting swapped? 
Shouldn't the output be Good Morning Hello?
Thank you.

Comment: Question is ugly, but it is NOT a dupe. Yes, it's about call-by-value, but this is not book about programming theory but Q&A site.

Answer (score 0):

Because items are copied. Method swaps two copied came with arguments and drops them.